# Sleep и PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я разрабатываю бота для телеграм, и использую для этого библиотеку PyTelegramBotApi.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
После того как пользователь отправляет сообщение, у меня стоит sleep на 3 секунды(не спрашивайте зачем, так надо).
Проблема в том, что в эти 3 секунды пользователь может написать что-нибудь, например выбрать на клавиатуре "Главное меню", и тогда его переведет в главное меню, и после этого придет сообщение которое должно было отправиться после sleep, и c этого момента все идет по одному месту. Как можно решить данную проблему?

UPD: Сообщение пользователя - это анимированный эмодзи, и сообщение должно отправиться после того как вся анимация была проиграна. Убрать sleep = убить весь интерес

Comment: Для начала написать, зачем (какую проблему решает) `sleep`. Это неправильный способ решить какую-то другую проблему. Ее нужно описать.

Answer (score -1):

Создайте глобальную переменную и изменяйте её на False перед sleep и после sleep меняйте её на True. И перед открытии меню и других ломающих всё операциях сделайте if название переменной.

UPD: забыл добавить, лучше создать словарь, в котором ключом будет id пользователя.